# WkWebView instances and memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I wonder if there is a way to reduce or reuse instances of a wkwebview, since every time a method is implemented on a wkwebview

```
wkWebView.load(myRequest)
```

a web instance is generated and remains in memory, and I can see them all while debugging with Safari:

[image]

Every time the same page is shown, the memory consumption increases:

[image]

Loading "about: blank" does not solve the problem, as well as wkWebView = nil.

Comment: the only option I have found while experiencing this is to no open so many instances of Webview, I did have to dismiss view controller to open next with webview.

Comment: Optionnaly if you know that there will not be that many of web views you can create brand new `WKProcessPool` for this webview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some research, I found my mistake:

```
let webConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let userController:WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
userController.add(self, name: "interOp")
```

In viewDidLoad was causing memory leak, since that userController was never been released (and for the wkwebview, too).

My solution is: declare the WKUserContentController in the class of the viewController containing the wkWebView:

```
var userController: WKUserContentController  = WKUserContentController()
```

reference to it in viewDidLoad:

```
userController.add(self, name: "interOp")
webConfig.userContentController = userController;
```

and release it in viewWillDisappear:

```
userController.removeScriptMessageHandler(forName: "interOp")
```

Maybe it is not the better way to manage this problem, but it works. When the view will be dismissed, it leave nothing in Safari and release his memory occupation:

[image]

Comment: Nice, for me it was the removeScriptMessageHandler() that released the resources. Have an upvote. :)